# Generate a clock delay by fixed cycles number Verilog

Tags: signals, verilog, clock

I have a clock which is always active, I have another clock call it "sample" , which is generated from the first clock . I want to generate a delay of "sample" signal by fixed number of cycles of the first clock signal in verilog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use a **shift register**:

```
parameter DELAY = number_of_clock_cycles_you_want_to_delay_by;

reg [DELAY-1:0] shift_reg;

always @(posedge clk)
    begin
          shift_reg <= { shift_reg[DELAY-2:0], signal_you_want_to_delay};
    end

assign delayed_signal = shift_reg[DELAY-1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike.
I am a newbie with verilog, can you explain the assignment inside the always block ? Thanks

Comment: The curly brackets mean concatenation. Here we stick together (concatenate) our new signal at the LSB with the values in our shift register. The oldest signal is not needed any more so we drop the MSB of shift_reg. Each bit inside shift_reg is effectively getting pushed along by one every clock cycle towards the MSB, until it is assigned to delayed_signal after DELAY clock cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a count down counter, otherwise, it keeps shifting to the left without ending.